# How do I get my BlackRapid camera strap to stay on my shoulder?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, camera-straps

I've been using a BlackRapid sport camera strap for a year now, and it works great, except while shooting. It is very comfortable while the camera is hanging and offers great support, but as soon as I lift my camera, the shoulder part falls down along the arm, since there is no weight keeping it in place. Recently I was wearing a jacket and didn't notice it falling down, and the camera almost dropped to the ground.

Is this the way it is supposed to work or am I doing something wrong? I tried to close the under the arm part quite tight, and tried it loose, but nothing changed. Actually tight, it tended to pull it towards the arm even more. Is there something that can be done to prevent this?

Comment: Put the strap right across your head (so it's on your left shoulder if the camera is hanging on your right hip) - like an archetypal school nerd carries his bag.

Comment: well that is exactly what i do.. but if my right hand lifts the camera, there is no more weight on the shoulder (obviously) and tehrefore there is nothing holding the strap in position, and the strap slips down the LEFT shoulder along the arm..

Comment: Try wearing the strap under the jacket. That is what I do.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you wear it as intended, or even not quite as intended

<sup>please excuse the "fine art" ;-)</sup>

[image] [image]

Then there's the possibility it can fall off.

If you wear it not as intended, over your head

[image]

then it has no escape.

Comment: i wear it as intended, (second picture on top).. so basically you say to wear it wrong in order to solve a design flaw?

Comment: Essentially, yes. I don't have that exact type, but use a similar method on a more generic one. On one shoulder & under the other arm & it simply cannot fall off, the loop length is too short to reach your shoulder.

Comment: Nice fine art :o)